# Showing a file tree with parent relation with data from a sql query

Tags: mysql, json, servlets, tree, jstl

I'm currently working on my final project for my university, but unfortunately I stopped in this part, because I tried several things like trying to pass a variable with a list inside from servlet to a jsp file to use in a json function from a project https://gist.github.com/smrchy/7040377 and render a tree.

Right now my project I render directly from a sql query which is not ordered and don't show the relationship.
[right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHMmF.jpg)
I created a constructor to create a array or list with the values and parameters in java class, when i try to send it through session or parameter doesn't work...

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
HttpSession sessao = request.getSession(false);
response.setContentType("application/json");

try {
    FicheiroDAO x = new FicheiroDAO();
    x.imprime();
    List<Ficheiro> lista = x.getLista();

    JSONObject json;
    JSONArray addresse = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject listas = new JSONObject();;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("id", lista.get(i).getId());
            json.put("parentid", lista.get(i).getPasta());
            json.put("name", lista.get(i).getNome());                    
            addresse.put(i, json);
        }
    } catch (JSONException jse) {
    }
    String s = addresse.toString();

    request.setAttribute("listagem", s);
    sessao.setAttribute("listagem", s);
    sessao.setAttribute("teste", "POST");
    request.setAttribute("teste", "POST");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("files.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

My sql engine is Mysql and the image showing the table of the files is on my comment where the id_pasta it's the parent of the file

So I stopped trying that way and right now I'm trying to run the select in the JSP using java JSTL to create the array.

So I need some help from you experts to know the best way and easier to show correctly what I pretend.
Many thanks and regards!

EDITED FOR MORE INFO:

The way I want to show is like this

> - one
>
>   - two
>
>     - four
>   - three
>   - five
>
>     - six

So in that way I can display in a easy way what I want...

Edited:
Failed try to save the information from result set query, any ideas?

```
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.98:3306/repual", "admin", "123");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select id_fich, nome_fich, tipo_fich, id_pasta from repual.ficheiro join repual.permissoes where (id_fich=id_ficheiro) and (id_utilizador='26' or dep like ('%'+'1'+'%')) and id_pasta!=2 order by nome_fich");

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Map<String, String> objeto = new HashMap<String, String>();
            ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                Map<String, String> lv = new HashMap<String, String>();
                lv.put("id", rs.getString("id_fich"));
                lv.put("parentid", rs.getString("id_pasta"));
                lv.put("name", rs.getString("nome_fich"));
                data.add(lv);    
            }

            //create 'dataMap' map object to make a complete FC datasource.

            Map<String, String> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();  
/*
    gson.toJson() the data to retrieve the string containing the
    JSON representation of the data in the array.
*/
            JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
            String json = gson.toJson(data); 

            con.close();
```

New update:

I changed the way to do, and I'm now trying this new way but unfortunately I can't get the array from the "scriptlet" into javascript to use in the methods already created.

Here is the code, can someone help me how Can I use the Json array in json code (javascript)?
I created the variable status to receive the array but no luck even testing the string sd to receive the value, so my idea was use the the array "arr" created from resultset to replace the array "sqlquery" manually created in javascript and use the functions to output the elements..

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONException"%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONArray"%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="com.google.gson.*" %>

<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix = "sql"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
        HttpSession sessao = request.getSession(false);
    %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<%
                String myVar = "sadsa";
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/repual", "root", "admin");
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select id_fich, nome_fich, tipo_fich, id_pasta from repual.ficheiro join repual.permissoes where (id_fich=id_ficheiro) and (id_utilizador='26' or dep like ('%'+'1'+'%')) and id_pasta!=2 order by nome_fich");
                
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();                
                while (rs.next()) 
                {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    obj.put("id", rs.getString("id_fich"));
                    obj.put("parentid", rs.getString("id_pasta"));
                    obj.put("name", rs.getString("nome_fich"));
                    arr.put(obj);    
                }   
                con.close();
                st.close();
                out.println(arr.toString());
                String sd = "asdsad"; 
        
%> 
        <h1>SQL Query to Tree</h1>

        <h3>The SQL query</h3>
        select id_fich, nome_fich, tipo_fich, id_pasta from ficheiro join permissoes where (id_fich = id_ficheiro) and (id_utilizador = '26' or dep like ('%' + '1' + '%')) and id_pasta != 2 order by nome_fich
        <pre id="sqlquery"></pre>


        <h3>The sorted query</h3>
        <pre id="sortedquery"></pre>

        <h3>The Tree</h3>
        <pre id="tree"></pre>

        <h3>HTML List</h3>
        <div id="htmllist"></div>
        
        <button type="button" onclick="downloadficheiro();">sadsaad</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="downloadficheir();">post</button>        

        <!-- jQuery 3 -->
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var _queryTreeSort = function (options) {
        var cfi, e, i, id, o, pid, rfi, ri, thisid, _i, _j, _len, _len1, _ref, _ref1;
        id = options.id || "id";
        pid = options.parentid || "parentid";
        ri = [];
        rfi = {};
        cfi = {};
        o = [];
        _ref = options.q;
        for (i = _i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; i = ++_i) {
            e = _ref[i];
            rfi[e[id]] = i;
            if (cfi[e[pid]] == null) {
                cfi[e[pid]] = [];
            }
            cfi[e[pid]].push(options.q[i][id]);
        }
        _ref1 = options.q;
        for (_j = 0, _len1 = _ref1.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
            e = _ref1[_j];
            if (rfi[e[pid]] == null) {
                ri.push(e[id]);
            }
        }
        while (ri.length) {
            thisid = ri.splice(0, 1);
            o.push(options.q[rfi[thisid]]);
            if (cfi[thisid] != null) {
                ri = cfi[thisid].concat(ri);
            }
        }
        return o;
    };

    var _makeTree = function (options) {
        var children, e, id, o, pid, temp, _i, _len, _ref;
        id = options.id || "id";
        pid = options.parentid || "parentid";
        children = options.children || "children";
        temp = {};
        o = [];
        _ref = options.q;
        for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            e = _ref[_i];
            e[children] = [];
            temp[e[id]] = e;
            if (temp[e[pid]] != null) {
                temp[e[pid]][children].push(e);
            } else {
                o.push(e);
            }
        }
        return o;
    };

    var _renderTree = function (tree) {
        var e, html, _i, _len;
        html = "<ul>";
        for (_i = 0, _len = tree.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            e = tree[_i];
            html += "<li>" + e.name;
            if (e.children != null) {
                html += _renderTree(e.children);
            }
            html += "</li>";
        }
        html += "</ul>";
        return html;
    };

    sqlquery = ([
        {"id": "456", "parentid": "123", "name": "Dogs"},
        {"id": 214, "parentid": 456, "name": "Labradors"},
        {"id": 123, "parentid": 0, "name": "Mammals"},
        {"id": 810, "parentid": 456, "name": "Pugs"},
        {"id": 919, "parentid": 456, "name": "Terriers"}
    ]);
    
    var status = document.getElementsByName("arr");
    
    
    $('#sqlquery').html(JSON.stringify(sqlquery, true, 2)); 
    
    sortedquery = _queryTreeSort({q: sqlquery})
    $('#sortedquery').html(JSON.stringify(sortedquery, true, 2));
    
    
    tree = _makeTree({q: sortedquery})
    $('#tree').html(JSON.stringify(tree, true, 2));
    htmllist = _renderTree(tree)
    $('#htmllist').html(htmllist);
    
        function downloadficheir() { // Eliminar uma pasta ou ficheiro
        var f = document.form;
        f.method = "post";
        f.action = 'listaficheiro                            ';
        f.submit();
    }
        function downloadficheiro() { // Eliminar uma pasta ou ficheiro
        var f = document.form;
        f.method = "get";
        f.action = 'abreficheiro';
        f.submit();
    }
    foo();
    
    function foo()
    {
        var value = $('#sd').val();
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Comment: Well I'm using mysql.. If you need more code from the constructor or other part let me know..

Comment: My currently SQL table for the files is http://i.imgur.com/MWoNJNK.jpg where the id_pasta is the id of the parent.

Comment: You can read the following article https://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: Thanks in advance, that really give the output I want, but how can I use it to render in the html like that? Looking at that tutorial one thing that comes to my mind is in that way I can render and show the correct order but other than that i can't display using bootstrap for example. But it's a start, better than now for sure.. Thanks my friend!

Comment: Ok, based on that result set, on your servlet method, you are going to build a json like structure(I'll use GSON), following an approach like this one,and on the client something like `jqtree` https://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/examples/02_load_json_data_from_server/

Comment: Yeah I already "installed the GSON library" into the project and I will try to pass the result set one more time. But if I understanded well, I create a new java file and create a method to make that and then I call that way? regards

Comment: The website you send me about the jqtree is very neat, it's moreless what I want to do, but I continue with the problem how can I take the result set to a array or object in json or gson. I edited the first post with that part but its not working.